Epoxy viewbinding IllegalStateException crash
Firebase Crashlytics reported this error which I am trying to reproduce. So far I was able to reproduce it inside the debugger by altering a value, but not in a normal build. Bellow are the two places that related closest to the class, as well as the fragment from which the generated classes are called.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The attribute name was defined in your data binding model (com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel) but a data variable of that name was not found in the layout.
       at nl.xxx.ItemHoldingCategorySectionHeaderBindingModel_.setDataBindingVariables(ItemHoldingCategorySectionHeaderBindingModel_.java:225)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel.setDataBindingVariables(DataBindingEpoxyModel.java:90)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel.bind(DataBindingEpoxyModel.java:62)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel.bind(DataBindingEpoxyModel.java:37)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyViewHolder.bind(EpoxyViewHolder.java:74)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.BaseEpoxyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BaseEpoxyAdapter.java:118)
       at com.airbnb.epoxy.BaseEpoxyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BaseEpoxyAdapter.java:20)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7847)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6646)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6917)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6757)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6753)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2362)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1622)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:687)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4645)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:4022)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1638)
       at nl.xxx.generic.widget.WrapContentViewPager.onMeasure(WrapContentViewPager.kt:95)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1921)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:632)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:452)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:750)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:551)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:537)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:486)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:750)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:551)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalCenterConstraints(Direct.java:668)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:544)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:486)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:224)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:693)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:160)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:291)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onMeasure(MotionLayout.java:2936)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:833)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:1031)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7390)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1036)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:28571)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:5203)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3973)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3288)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:11344)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1689)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1698)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1153)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1079)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1646)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

The java method where the crash happens (...BindingModel_.java):
@Override
protected void setDataBindingVariables(ViewDataBinding binding) {
  if (!binding.setVariable(BR.name, name)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("The attribute name was defined in your data binding model (com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel) but a data variable of that name was not found in the layout.");
  }
}

The setVariable function:
@Override
public boolean setVariable(int variableId, @Nullable Object variable)  {
    boolean variableSet = true;
    if (BR.name == variableId) {
        setName((java.lang.String) variable);
    }
    else {
        variableSet = false;
    }
        return variableSet;
}

The FragmentBindingController.kt function:
private fun bindSectionHeader(holdingCategorySection: HoldingCategorySectionUIModel) {
    holdingCategorySection.name ?: return

    itemHoldingCategorySectionHeader {
        id(holdingCategorySection.hashCode())
        name(holdingCategorySection.name)
    }
}

The Fragment itself:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="name"
            type="String" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/spacing_16">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Subtitle2OnBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/spacing_8"
            android:text="@{name}"
            tools:text="SomeText" />

        <include layout="@layout/layout_divider" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>

I tried different strings as inputs, changing the names of the variables in either the fragment or the controller and a lot of online digging.
This is my first post, so feedback would also be appreciated!
